# How to set object properties with classes in CoffeeScript

Tags: class, properties, coffeescript, instance

I'm trying to write a program that takes a number and validates it according to the Luhn formula.

How do I set object properties in the class in CoffeeScript? I want to do this:

```
class Luhn
  constructor: (@number)  ->

  lastDigit: @number % 10
```

But this produces:

```
function Luhn(number) {
  this.number = number;
}

Luhn.prototype.checkDigit = Luhn.number % 10;
```

Which returns `undefined`, because it's trying to access a class variable.

When setting the prototype, you can do this, though:

```
function Luhn(number) {
  this.number = number;
}

Luhn.prototype.lastDigit = function() {
  return this.number % 10
}
```

Now an instance of the `Luhn` class has a function `lastDigit()` which works.

Is there a way of setting object properties in the class in CoffeeScript? I know I can set it in the constructor, like this:

```
class Luhn
  constructor: (@number)  ->
    @lastDigit: @number % 10
```

But I want to set other, more complicated properties, and I don't want my constructor to become a mess. This is an idea, but it still kinda sucks:

```
class Luhn
  constructor: (@number)  ->
    @lastDigit: @number % 10
    @complicatedProperty1 = getComplicatedProperty1(@number)
    @complicatedProperty2 = getComplicatedProperty2(@number)
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set them in the `constructor`, that's the only place where you have an instance to work with.

Alternatively, use a method instead of a simple property:

```
class Luhn
  constructor: (@number)  ->

  lastDigit: -> @number % 10
```

or:

```
class Luhn
  constructor: (@number)  ->

  lastDigit: -> @number % 10

  complicatedProperty1: ->
    @_complicatedProperty1 ?= getComplicatedProperty1(@number)
```

The caching inside `complicatedProperty1` assumes that `@number` won't be changing and that `getComplicatedProperty1(@number)` won't return `null` or `undefined`.

A CoffeeScript class isn't really a C-style `struct` so exposing everything as plain properties isn't the best idea ever. If you need easy access to just the properties, then provide a `toJSON` or `serialize` method to do so without exposing your internals to accidental modification:

```
toJSON: ->
  number: @number
  lastDigit: @lastDigit()
  complicatedProperty1: @complicatedProperty1()
```

I used `toJSON` as the name as [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) will call that method when it tries to stringify an object:

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON` method when called will be serialized.

so `toJSON` is a natural name of serialization functions in (Coffee|Java)Script.

Comment: is this documented anywhere? As I thought `class { x: 1}` would work as expected

Comment: @phil294: It sort of does work expect, [for example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20C%0A%20%20x%3A%201%0A%20%20m%3A%20-%3E%20%40x%0Ac%20%3D%20new%20C%0Ac.x%20%3D%2011%0Aconsole.log(c.constructor%3A%3Ax%2C%20c.x%2C%20c.m())). But note that the question is about `lastDigit: @number % 10` rather than `lastDigit: 6`.